# how to display Hindi and English data together to html using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Below mention string, I am trying to show on html page using AngularJS.
(This string stored in db (UTF-8), contains Hindi and English text data.
while this same string works fine in PHP(mysql) when retrieving this data from db and displaying but not working with Angularjs (nodejs + postgresql))

HTML file charset:encoding=UTF-8 charset=UTF-8

```
$scope.str ="Directions: In questions no. 1 to 4, select the related word/letters/numbers from the given alternatives:
 à¤¨à¤¿à¤°à¥à¤¦à¥‡à¤¶ : à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤¶à¥à¤¨ à¤¸à¤‚à¤–à¥à¤¯à¤¾ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤¦à¤¿à¤¯à¥‡ à¤—à¤¯à¥‡ à¤µà¤¿à¤•à¤²à¥à¤ªà¥‹à¤‚ à¤®à¥‡à¤‚ à¤¸à¥‡ à¤¸à¤‚à¤¬à¤¨à¥à¤§à¤¿à¤¤ à¤¶à¤¬à¥à¤¦ / à¤…à¤•à¥à¤·à¤° / à¤¸à¤‚à¤–à¥à¤¯à¤¾ à¤•à¥‹ à¤šà¥à¤¨à¤¿à¤ 

 FINGERS : HAND :: ? : FEET
 à¤…à¤‚à¤—à¥à¤²à¥€:à¤¹à¤¾à¤¥ :: ? : à¤ªà¥ˆà¤°".
```

Comment: It is not really possible to tell where the problem is based on the given informtion. You could have screwed up the encoding at multible places (wrong encoding, while saving in th db, wrong encodeing for the db connecting while fetching, wrong encoding while delivering to the browser, ...). You would need to take a look at each step that was done to create the provided snipped to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Not using encoding at all because NodeJS by default encodes it into 'UTF-8'.

Comment: Well you must do something wrong ith the encoding (e.g. not defining any at all where it is required), otherwise the text would look correctly. Anyhow how should the text look correctly if it would have been encoded correctly. Post the text `$scope.str` should contain. My guess is that a part of the text is uft-16 encoded as some point and is later converted incorrectly.

Comment: Not using encoding at all because NodeJS by default encodes it into 'UTF-8'. In Angularjs just displaying data to view(Whatever we get). Above mentioned string is copied from table (copying a column of table) and node API output also gives same as it.

Comment: `[...]Above mentioned string is copied from table (copying a column of table)[...]` if the text looks like that in the database and you copy it that way that it was already wrong in the database. The hindi signs have to be human readable in both the database and in the js file.

Comment: yes its same in db too. I imported table from mysql(table:collection->utf8_bin) to postgresql(db: colletion-> en_US.UTF-8).     when i was working with php (mysql) on above data it worked. but even using any of database with nodejs and angularjs its not working.

Comment: Well then you know your answer, you had that data in the wrong encoding in your mysql databse all the time and you copied it in the wrong encoding into postgress. It is a common mistake that people set the wrong encoding for the database connection and that they save the data the wrong way. It works in php as you do the same mistake while saving to the database and reading from it, so it seems to work fine (but its still wrong).

Comment: thank you very much for helping @t.niese

Comment: I find this to fix this problem by modifying column:                                                                                           alter table ssc_cgl_paper_1 modify questioncontent varchar(2000) character set latin1;
alter table descriptions modify name blob;
alter table descriptions modify name VARCHAR(2000) character set utf8